# How to add a passwordbox to dialog in Mahapp

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

inside my wpf application i have a dialog(Mahapp control) and i need to add a passwordbox to this dialog instead of the textinput.Any ideas of how to do that.

```
 private async void ShowModalDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.IsEnabled = false;
     this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = UseAccentForDialog.IsEnabled ? MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented : MetroDialogColorScheme.Theme;
     var result = await this.ShowInputAsync("FERMETURE DE L'APPLICATION.", "Tu dois demander à tes parents pour quitter." + "\n" + "Indiquer votre mot de passe pour quitter l'application.");
     var wcf = new ServiceReferenceParent.ParentServiceClient();
     Parent par = wcf.GetParent(parent.ParentId);
    if (result == par.Password) //user pressed cancel
        Application.Current.Shutdown() ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no available implementation, you will need to create your own dialog.

See the [MahApps.Metro Dialog section at github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Controls/Dialogs) for further details whether your concern was implemented or not. You may also replace the `TextBox` control by a `PasswordBox` control in the present code. This shouldn't be a problem since we are talking about just one control which isn't actually quite different than the `TextBox`.

**UPDATE:**

As I was researching for my current project, I found an [issue](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/pull/1276) in the MahApps.Metro repository where someone released a login dialog. You might want to check this out. I'm going to use that now.

Comment: ok thanks for your help but i have another problem:in my application i have a frame , and thi dialog is not displayed when i use the frame to navigate throught the internet.

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide as much details as possible. I don't get which problem you have by just reading that comment.

Comment: @RamiRaddaoui See my update, you might be interested in that one. :P

Comment: That's kind of you Mostey :)
I will try it right now